# can you help me with this error in android studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to run a project that is using a C++ module i try everything and nothing works it still get this error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':pulseandroid:compileDebugNdk'.

> Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
>   Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration with the stable Android Gradle plugin:
>    https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
>   or use the experimental plugin:
>    https://developer.android.com/studio/build/experimental-plugin.html.

Comment: Please change the thread name to something descriptive of your problem.

Comment: Did you read the links given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Make sure NDK is install

2 - Put this part in `build.gradle(Module:app)` above `buildTypes{}`

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}
buildTypes{}
```